# C programming--- how to save a string with spaces in FILE and recall them

Tags: c

I saw few similar problems in this website and tried to follow those methods but either those methods don't work properly or I couldn't understand properly.

I am having trouble with saving strings with spaces into file and recalling them.

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
   char a[200];
   char b[200];
   char c[200];
   char bug[100];
   int s;
   FILE *fp;
   printf("Press 1 to add\nPress 2 to show\n");
   scanf("%d",&s);
   if(s==1)
      goto level1;
   else
      goto level2;
   level1:
      gets(bug);
      printf("Name: ");
      gets(a);
      printf("Address: ");
      gets(b);
      printf("Comment: ");
      gets(c);
      fp=fopen("practice2.txt", "a+");
      fprintf(fp, "\n%s\t%s\t%s\t",a,b,c);
      fclose(fp);
      printf("\n1 for add\n2 for show\n");
      scanf("%d",&s);
      if(s==1)
         goto level1;
      else
         goto level2;
      level2:
         fp=fopen("practice2.txt", "r");
         if(fp==0)
            printf("\nEmpty\n");
         else
         {
            while(!feof(fp))
            {
               fscanf(fp, "\n%s\t%s\t%s\t",&a,&b,&c);
               printf("%s\n%s\n%s\n\n",a,b,c);
            }
         }
         fclose(fp);
         return 0;
}
```

This code works if I input strings with no spaces like "Hello_people". But if I input strings with spaces like "Hello people", then it doesn't show proper output. I am working on a project in c programming and got stuck with this problem.

Btw, in line number 17, I used gets(bug). Because I found out that if i use gets() after scanf(), then it doesn't take the first gets() input. So I tried using an extra gets() after scanf() and then it works.

I am a very beginner in programming. Please can anyone help me by fixing my code to make it work perfectly?

---

Additional info:

[image]

If I input:

```
Name: Shane Watson
Address: Australia
Comment: I like him
```

Then I expect it to show the result exactly this way.

Comment: Uurelated to the question, but those gotos are really ugly.

Comment: what alternative of goto do you use? thjis small code can be written without gotos, yes. but i find it useful for doing my project of nearly thousand lines. what do you use in those cases?

Comment: @jake: I recommend you get yourself [a good book on C](http://stackoverflow.com/a/562377/253056) and study it ASAP, before you pick up too many bad habits (like using `goto` instead of loops).

Comment: @paul thanks for your advice. but can you please elaborate why is goto a bad habit? does it have some bindings or doesn't it work properly or anything like that?

Comment: @jake: `goto` is generally considered harmful for a variety of reasons, but mainly it breaks the concept of *structured programming*. There are some fairly rare cases where a `goto` might be appropriate. but in general, and particularly as a beginner, you should completely avoid it and learn structured programming with loops etc.

Comment: @jake: also, on another point, see: [Why is “while ( !feof (file) )” always wrong?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5431941/253056)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
char a[200];
char b[200];
char c[200];
char line[200];
char bug[100];
int s;
FILE *fp;
printf("Press 1 to add\nPress 2 to show\n");
scanf("%d",&s);
if(s==1)
  goto level1;
else
  goto level2;
level1:
gets(bug);
//scanf("% [^\n]s" , &a);
    printf("Name:");
  //fflush(stdin);
  scanf("% [^\n]s" , &a);
  fgets(a, 200, stdin);
  printf("Address: ");
  scanf("% [^\n]s" , &b);
  fgets(b, 200, stdin);

  printf("Comment: ");
  scanf("% [^\n]s" , &c);
  fgets(c, 200, stdin);

  fp=fopen("practice2.txt", "a+");

  fprintf(fp, "\n %s %s %s",a,b,c);
  fclose(fp);

  printf("\n1 for add\n2 for show\n");
  scanf("%d",&s);
  if(s==1)
     goto level1;
  else
     goto level2;

  level2:
     fp=fopen("practice2.txt", "r");
     if(fp==0)
        printf("\nEmpty\n");
     else
     {
        //while(!feof(fp))
        while(fgets(line , sizeof(line), fp))
        {
           //fscanf(fp, "\n %s \t %s \t %s \t",&a,&b,&c);
           printf("%s",line);
        }
     }
     fclose(fp);
     return 0;
```

}

Comment: `fflush(stdin)` results in undefined behaviour on most platforms and should not be used - `fflush` should only be used on **output** streams.

Comment: @PaulR thank you for that comment. I have edited my solution without **fflush(stdin)** . You can remove the negative 1. :)

Comment: @jake check the edited code now :) This will help you.

Answer (score 1):

```
    char input[200];
    printf("\n\tEnter the name \n");
    scanf("% [^\n]s" , &input);
    fgets(input, 200, stdin);
```

This code should work for you. The initial scanf is used to empty the buffer. The code is fairly simple to understand.

> You should avoid using gets as it is impossible to know that how many characters **gets()** will use.

I have given detailed answer to your question here. 
https://stackoverflow.com/a/43279647/7829296

Comment: not working. i must be doing it wrong. 
please it is a request, can you add your method in my code and send? please help

Comment: What is the error you get or what input goes to the file? Share the screenshot

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/43280393/7757267

here @tushitjain. please help

Answer (score 0):

%s - specifier, allow to read you whole word till delimeter , dont remember exact delimeter list , but `'space' '\n' '\0' '\t'` are 100% in there

you may use a buffer where you read until '\n' and then do everything you want with it.

```
int main() {
    const int max_size = 1000;
    char tmp_symbol;
    char arr[max_size];
    int arr_counter = 0;

    while (true /*some code */) {
        scanf("%c", &tmp_symbol);
        if (tmp_symbol != '\n' /* '\t' or other delims you need*/)
            arr[arr_counter++] = tmp_symbol;
        else break /* or something , like perform your line*/;
    }

    // here i have whole line in arr;
    return 0;
}
```

---

try this, but its not that perfect

```
char* read_line(char* destination, FILE* source) {
    char tmp_symb; int counter = 0;
     while (true) {
        fscanf(source ,"%c", &tmp_symb);
        if (tmp_symb != '\n' && tmp_symb != EOF)
            destination[counter++] = tmp_symb;
        else return destination;
     };
}
```

use in places where you use `"%s"`, and make some array like `char temporary[200]`

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. But I am sorry to say that I can't understand where to apply your method.....
Can you PLEASE PLEASE include your method in my code?